# sed to extract text from multiple text files

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

Lets say, I have two input files, `fileA.txt` and `fileB.txt`. The files are like this:

```
FileA.txt
Color
yellow
orange
black
Fruit
apple
banana
Weekday
monday
sunday

FileB.txt
Color
blue
green
Fruit
melon
Weekday
saturday
tuesday
thursday
```

I would like to extract the information  below `Color`, `Fruit`, `Weekday` in all files and create a new one for each field . So, my output is 3 files, `Color.txt`, `Fruit.txt` and `Weekday.txt` like this.

```
Color.txt
Color_A
yellow
orange
black
Color_B
blue
green

Fruit.txt
Fruit_A
apple
banana
Fruit_B
melon
```

And similar for `Weekday.txt`

I hope now is more clear, Thanks.

Comment: can't help with this as your example output doesn't clearly define your end  goal (IMHO). Why not get all data for `hp1` (from all files) into 1 file named `hp1`? That makes more sense to me. If you can think of a better way to explain your goal using illustrative data, you'll get better help. Also, you're almost certain to find that `awk` will be much easier for these sort of text file manipulations. That I said, I know learning a new paradigm can be daunting, so keep trying and good luck.

Comment: What did you try? And yes, look at `awk` for this.

Comment: Getting all data for hp1 (from all files) into 1 file named hp1 will work. However, I also want to associate data with file.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, and do you have 20 inputfiles named `namefile1 .. namefile20`, an unknown number of keyfields `hpnnn` with nnn any number and exactly 1 line of information after each `hpnnn` key ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @Walter

Comment: Go for `awk`. Using a `for`-loop over `namefile*` with the results of `grep -A2 "^hp" | grep -v "^hp"` will lead to a slow solution.

Comment: @SRivero : Do you understand how important a clear specification is? The reason no one has offered to help is that they will have to read these comments to find out what you really need. Update your Q to show a better (small) example of inputs (which you have done) and required outputs(not so good). This can probably be solved in 1 line of awk code. Good luck!!!

Comment: @shellter. Thank you for your interest and help. I have changed the question to make more clear the output files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{suffix=substr(FILENAME,5,1)}
         /Color|Fruit|Weekday/{file=$1".txt"; $1=$1"_"suffix}
             {print > file}' FileA.txt FileB.txt                   


$ head {Fruit,Color,Weekday}.txt          

==> Fruit.txt <==                                                                                                     
Fruit_A
apple
banana
Fruit_B
melon

==> Color.txt <==
Color_A
yellow
orange
black
Color_B
blue
green

==> Weekday.txt <==
Weekday_A
monday
sunday
Weekday_B
saturday
tuesday
thursday
```

Answer (score 0):

In POSIX shell script (i.e. bash, dash, etc.):

```
rm Color.txt Fruit.txt Weekday.txt  # old files will spoil this.
for f in A B
do
    while read x
    do 
        L=${x%${x#?}}
        l=$(echo $L | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
        if [ $L != $l ]
        then
            F=$x.txt
            echo ${x}_$f >> $F
        else
            echo $x >> $F
        fi
    done < File$f.txt
done
```

output:

```
head {Fruit,Color,Weekday}.txt
==> Fruit.txt <==
Fruit_A
apple
banana
Fruit_B
melon

==> Color.txt <==
Color_A
yellow
orange
black
Color_B
blue
green

==> Weekday.txt <==
Weekday_A
monday
sunday
Weekday_B
saturday
tuesday
thursday
```

How it works: on hold. (I'm worried this is a schoolwork problem, maybe it would be better if the OP figures the above shell code out, then explains or criticizes as need be.)